# When bash jq parsing json ,return a multi-line array but, how can I use this result?

Tags: json, bash, jq

when I use the command:

```
ids=`cat $myfilename | jq -r "[.data[].id]"`
```

and return like this:

```
[
  "PC_PACX_0017",
  "GS_ZGRS_0001",
  "PC_PACX_0018",
  "GS_ZGRS_0002",
  "AB_HXJK_0002",
  "AB_HXJK_0001",
  "TK_TKZX_0011",
  "TL_TBAL_0002",
  "TL_TBAL_0001",
  "TS_TKRS_0001",
  "TS_TKRS_0002",
  "TS_TKRS_0003"
]
```

but it can't be seen as a array, it's length only be 1.How can I use this result?

Answer (score 0):

An array is distinct from a multi-line string. Assuming there are no newlines in your data, changing your `jq` call to

```
jq -r '[.data[].id]|.[]'  # Could be simplified to '.data[].id'
```

and use `readArray` (`bash` 4 or later) to populate a proper array.

```
readArray -t ids < <(jq -r '[.data[].id]|.[]' "$myfilename")
```

Comment: It's an ordinary input redirection. However, `<(...)` is a construct called process substitution, which make the output of a command appear as a file.

Comment: For robustness and generality, use the -c command-line option.